# add class to book navigation block links

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I use navigation block generated by block module. Tha block is displayes on all pages that belongs to book. I would like to add custom class to all links inside navigation block. I found that the block is generated by code here>

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.module/function/book_block_view/7

But I am unable to figure out how to alter links. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [Block class module](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class): Block Class allows users to add classes to any block through the block's configuration interface. By adding a very short snippet of PHP to a theme's block.tpl.php file, classes can be added to the parent `<div class="block ...">` element of a block.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I need to add classes to links in menu, not to a block.

Comment: Try `menu attributes` module: https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes for adding class to menu links.

Comment: I came across this, but one can not edit book menu.